# The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I tried to get all records from my db and it works fine with:

```
$client->scan([
      'TableName' => 'MyTableName'
    ]);
```

Now when I try to get a specific record using following code i get Exception: The provided key

```
$client->getItem([
            'TableName' => 'MyTableName',
            'Key' => [
                'id'  => ['S' => '1234abcd']
            ]
        ]);
```

Note that I have no indexes created for the table and type of my id column is string.

**Edit**: Added partition key, still the same error:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your `id` **primary key** is simple and not composite? In other words, you don't have a partition key AND a sort key in your table.

Comment: @KhalidT. does that fall under indexes? coz as I mentioned, I have no indexes created for the table. If not, how do I do that or any link that would help?

Comment: If you have a primary key, then you DO HAVE an index. When you say you don't have an index, you probably mean that "you don't have a secondary index" since Amazon DynamoDB creates and maintains indexes for the primary key attributes automatically. You just need to make sure you're providing the proper primary key for the table when calling the `getItem` method (i.e., partition key and sort key, if exists).

Comment: @KhalidT. I dont have a primary key on that table.

Comment: @KhalidT. added partition key, see editted above - included the image.